# How can I get iTunes to automatically refresh the media library?

Tags: itunes

Most of the media players that have a "media library" functionality usually self-refresh the library when files are added or removed. As I share the media library with other media players (I use iTunes only to copy music on the iPod), I would like iTunes to automatically refresh when I add, remove, or rearrange audio tracks in the file system. How can I get iTunes to do this?

Comment: To me it seems a legitimate question, and a problem common to a lot of people: audio tracks added to the music folder don't show up in iTunes. Calling it "a rant" is just a fanboyism.

Comment: First of all, I am anything but an apple "fanboy".  Second, I see only 2 questions here.  The first is "why did apple choose design implementation x?", which can not be answered except by a team of apple engineers.  The second is really just commentary on the first, disguised as a question ("how can I work around this design flaw?").

Comment: It's a legitimate question.  I don't interpret this as "why did Apple use design X" it's "I expect all media players to have this feature, and I can't find it in iTunes--does it exist?  If so, how do  I do it?"

Answer (score 8):

What you call a “design” flaw, is not such thing. It’s a design decision made by the iTunes team. Although iTunes lets you “manually manage your library”, it’s never intended to let you move things around in the filesystem, add, remove or modify files.

The premise for iTunes happiness is that you always add the items to the library and *modify things from within iTunes*. You have the choice to let iTunes “organize” the library (which will copy the *media* to the iTunes library folder and organize it there as he wants) or you can leave it wherever you originally had it, but iTunes doesn’t “read” or “monitor" the filesystem for changes. It knows things changed when the *library.xml* is changed, and the only application that does that is iTunes itself.

**Is this the best way?**

Yes and no, it has advantages, but a lot of people miss the “Winamp-like” ease of use and it’s understandable. On the other hand, it simplifies a lot of things for a lot of people. It has decently worked for quite a few years now.

But that’s the topic for another discussion. :)

Comment: I understand that Apple tries to design software for dummies that don't deal with the file system, but there are also some power users forced to various reason to use Apple products, so they could add some option also for this type of users

Comment: I’m a power user then given that I interact with multiple OSs and program for a few of them for a living, and yet I couldn’t care less about where iTunes puts my music. It’s a bunch of mp3/4, I have other things to do with my time than worry about that. As I’ve said, it has drawbacks and advantages. Power user is not the line that divides it in this case. Some people cares, some people couldn’t care less. Welcome to Apple’s world, where things are… well… the way they want it.

Comment: It is actually a world I don't like... but I'm forced to use it due to the iPod... By the way, I really care of my personal data: pictures, documents, ebook, music... the way I organize them in folders (and subfolders) is not what the program does.

Comment: You have two choices: a) Change your music player, b) adapt to the way it works. Get used to drag your music to iTunes, organize the tags in iTunes, make sure your library works fine. Have new music? Drag it to iTunes, not to the filesystem. Yeah, if you come from the Winamp world, it’s a pain, but iTunes, as bad as it is, does a decent job organizing the music and finding it real fast.

Comment: I use iTunes only for syncing, I use foobar2000 as media player. What I should change is the hardware media player, and it is something I'll do soon (at the time, I share an iPod touch as a device for testing the apps I develope and as my personal MP3 player).

Comment: I'm pretty sure Martin was only trying to answer the question you actually asked, not read your mind and figure out whatever it is that you're trying to get at.  If you want help around here I would suggest figuring out what you want help with before asking.

Comment: @Lorenzo Yes, if you’re not comfortable with your current music player, the best you can do it change it, maybe a Zune will do. ;)

Comment: @calavera ;) It’s ok, some people dislike iTunes or certain things about the Apple world as much as a lot of people hates other ecosystems. But it’s true that this is not the place for those arguments. To each his own.

Comment: @Martin: unfortunately the Zune is not marketed in my country, and then the iPod is painfully some sort of standard, as my car and my HiFi both have support for that crappy iTunes-player... ahem... fabulous MP3 player.

Comment: @Lorenzo Working with Windows CE, I see why you hate things in general ;)

Comment: I just tried the "create MP3 version" feature of iTunes, and it created duplicates of the whole album, and put them in the same directory as the others. I then moved them out via Windows and wanted to refresh that directory/album. No way to do that. What would you suggest is the correct way to do that?

Comment: -1: this isn't an/the answer. explaining how itunes works does not tell me how to get itunes to auto-refresh. I wish there was a real answer to this. Seems like the original question was more of a rant, but the edited version present now is very valid. Regardless of how itunes is designed, it'd be nice to know how to accomplish this auto-refresh.

Comment: @JT703 Your desire to have what you call a real answer, doesn't change the fact that there's no need for such, because iTunes is not designed to work that way. This cannot be accomplished, and will possibly never be accomplished by iTunes, the answer explains this, and it's still valid.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini - since you don't understand what a real answer is, scroll down the page a bit or click this link: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/79364

Comment: @JT703 if that's what you consider and answer, have fun with it. The answer only covers windows (something not mentioned by the original question, so we usually assume it's OS X since this is an Apple forum), second, it's an external application, not an iTunes solution, and it can stop working with any update.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini - a partial answer is better than no answer. You gotta think about this from the perspective of someone who really wants to know how to accomplish this (like me). I come to stackexchange sites to find real solutions to problems. While it's clear that you understand that iTunes can't accomplish this, it'd be nice to see the green check mark on an answer that helps accomplish the goal of the question, not say that it's impossible. I agree, that the ideal answer would cover all the OSs, but I know for me, that answer was THE answer that helped me.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Martin's answer, I would point out that a major reason for this design decision is speed.  If iTunes had to scan the filesystem for changes every time it ran, the program could potentially slow to a crawl.

There are a number of tricks and third party utilities you can use to get around this behavior.  The [wiki for MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/iTunes_Guide#Updating_Library_in_iTunes) has some quick tips on refreshing metadata info, like using the "Get Info" menu item to refresh individual track information.  They also detail a small AppleScript that will refresh multiple tracks at once.

As for adding and removing files, the best way to get around this is to not try to get around it in the first place.  Use the "Add to Library" and "Delete" functions in iTunes itself.  However, if you do decide to remove files without using the iTunes "Delete" function, you can use a script such as ["Super Remove Dead Tracks"](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=removedeadsuper) from [Doug's Apple Scripts For iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/).

Comment: Thank for your useless advice to not manage files manually. If you'd read my question (and not only the title), you would know that I only use iTunes to sync iPod (as I can't just drag and drop my music into it).

Comment: If you'd read my answer (and not only my name since you apparently don't like my answer to your question on SuperUser), you'd would know that the fact you only use iTunes to sync iPod has no bearing whatsoever on the answer provided.  If you're asking some sort of different question, maybe you should make that question clear.

Comment: And yes, I think you should definitely get different hardware, since, as stated in your profile, you "hate: Apple, iTunes, Steve Jobs, the iPhone, the iPad, Mac OS, and especially the Dock."

Answer (score 3):

Itunes Folder Watch is the external app you require for this functionality  http://albumbrowser.klarita.net/itfw.html

Comment: It might be worth noting that this application is Windows only and more or less replicates the functionality of the "Add to iTunes" folder

Answer (score 3):

My answer is use a different music manager. That is what I have done. iTunes use to pickup on new music I added but now you have to put it the "watch folder" and of course then it moves it from there into the library.  That wont work when I use Google Music Manager and have my cloud music sync to my hard drive.  So iTunes is out for me.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have found success is deleting the itunes index and then adding the main directory of music again....sucks but seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm running iTunes in Windows) I had to do it the hard way after running a program to remove duplicates from my computer. I changed the location of my iTunes library in preferences. Then, I selected all songs in iTunes and deleted them (they didn't delete off of my original library location).

I then changed my library location back to where my music is located.

Then, I opened Windows explorer and navigated to the folder where all of my music is and selected all the folders except the "Automatically add to iTunes" folder. I dragged all music folders into the "Automatically add to iTunes" folder and moved them there.

iTunes detected them and then refreshed the library.

It was a small hassle, but at least my duplicate files are gone now.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, I don't know that you can get iTunes to automatically track changes, but here's one possible work-around.

I keep my music on an external hard drive, and whenever I add new music to it, I go to File -> Add Folder to Library, and point it to my external HDD.  I also have (under Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced) unchecked the "Keep iTunes Media folder organized" and "Copy files to iTunes...".

This works for adding files, but unfortunately does not detect removed files.  It also means that you'll only be able to add files to your devices when the HDD is attached.

I also have "Manually manage music" selected for my ipod, but I don't think that's related to how I store my music.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the above answer: I put all new music to be added to the iPod in a seperate folder then point iTunes to this folder under "add folder". I then add these files/folders to my HDD library and delete them from the seperate folder. 'Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

if using window 7 you can move all music files o itunes . itunes media . music
then right click music library properties remove the current monitered folder change it to the itunes >itunes media > music 
you will have to do something simaler with windows media player 
open window media player orginize>mange librarys>music remove the current monitered folder add tunes >itunes media > music to monitered folders
To clear the Windows Media Player database, follow these steps:
a. Exit Windows Media Player.
b. Click Start, click Run, type %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Media Player, and then click OK.
c. Select all the files in the folder, and then click Delete on the File menu.
Note: You do not have to delete the folders that are in this folder.
d. Restart Windows Media Player.
Note: Windows Media Player automatically rebuilds the database.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if this answer is located elsewhere in the thread. I didn't see it, so figured I would add my two cents worth. The easiest way I found to do this is to just re-add the library folder (without deleting the library because that is time consuming and unnecessary) for example. I keep all my movies on an external drive in a folder marked iPod Movies, and not in my iTunes media folder that is designated in my preferences. So, whenever I add new movies to that external drive, I just re-add the iPod Movies folder "File>Add Folder to Library>". It always adds the new movies I've put in the iPod Movies Folder. It is still a manual process, but it is quick and it adds all movies I've added since the last time I did this, and it is free and doesn't use up memory running in the background (unlike the albumbrowser recommended above). Hope this helps

Comment: It is not a thread - and read all the other answers first I have down voted as I can't be bothered to read more than the second sentence - see  http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52900/237